# count the number of rows with a condition with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python-2.7, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a sqlite table like this. Which has 3 columns. I want to 
count the number of rows where user_id = 1 
is this possible with SQLAlchemy?

```
class UserImage(db.Model):
        id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
        user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
        photo = db.Column(db.String(250))
```

This will return all the rows. How to modify this to get my expected result.
rows = db.session.query(func.count(UserImage.user_id)).scalar()

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 23):

You can do it like this:

```
UserImage.query.filter(UserImage.user_id == 1).count()
```

or

```
db.session.query(UserImage).filter(UserImage.user_id == 1).count()
```

Comment: I need to get the number of rows to a variable. do I have to use .scalar() also?

Comment: If you need the number of rows affected by your query you don't need scalar. Scalar will return object instances not the count of objects. *count* returns an integer value greater or equal to zero.

Comment: Is there a difference between the 1st method and the second?

Answer (score 4):

For SQLAlchemy 2.x style, you can get the count number like this:

```
from sqlalchemy import select, func

db.session.scalar(
  select(func.count()).
  select_from(User)
)

# or

db.session.scalar(select(func.count(User.id)))
```

Now with the condition:

```
db.session.scalar(
  select(func.count()).
  select_from(UserImage).
  filter(UserImage.user_id == 1)
)

# or

db.session.scalar(
  select(func.count(UserImage.id)).
  filter(UserImage.user_id == 1)
)
```

P.S. If you are using pure SQLAlchemy instead of Flask-SQlAlchemy, just replace `db.session` with `session`.

Comment: for this case: 
`db.session.execute(

  select(func.count(UserImage.id)).

  filter(UserImage.user_id == 1)
).scalars().one()` how should it look if I don't know what PK is or don't have one or don't want to reference any field names in func.count argument?

Comment: You can use `select(func.count()).select_from(UserImage).filter(UserImage.user_id == 1)`.