# How to count the number of rows from query with SQLAlchemy when no model is specified?

Tags: python-3.x, count, sqlalchemy

I'm looking for a way to count with SQLAlchemy the number of rows that is returned from a given query (that potentially includes filters) but everything I find on the net makes explicit use of a model (example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25605410/count-the-number-of-rows-with-a-condition-with-sqlalchemy)). My problem is that I don't have a model, I only have a Table object (because I'm dealing with temporary tables that vary in format from time to time). For the moment I can do the following:

```
tbl = Table(mytablename,metadata,autoload=True, autoload_with=myengine, schema=myschemaname)
query = select([tbl]) 
filters = build_filters(...) #my function that build filters
query = query.where(and_(*filters))
conn = myengine.connect()
ResultProxy = conn.execute(query)
totalCount = len(ResultProxy.fetchall())
```

but it's very inefficient. Is there a way to do the count efficiently and without referring to any model?

Comment: Are you looking to do a select count(*) on mytablename without actually querying all the records?

Comment: I want to count the number of rows returned by a query on a table yes but that query can include filters. I would like to do for example: select count(*) from mytable where temperature>80 and city=Dallas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the SQLAlchemy Core 'count' function documented [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/functions.html). I believe you can attach your filters on to that like you're doing now. So, (not guaranteeing my syntax here, but here's something to start you with)...

```
query = select([func.count()]).select_from(my_table).where(and_(*filters))
conn = myengine.connect()
ResultProxy = conn.execute(query)
totalCount = ResultProxy.fetchone()[0]
```

According to the documentation, I believe this will actually generate a SELECT COUNT from the database, not actually bring all the rows back from the DB and then count them.

Comment: Sorry but I'm not sure to understand. Did you mean 'count' instead of 'sum'? And could you give an example? I see how to do a count on my table (query = select([func.count()]).select_from(tbl)) but not on a my filtered query.

Comment: Sorry about that Patrick, yes, I meant count. I'll modify my answer to show that.

Comment: You're welcome, Patrick. Thanks for giving the chance to help!

Comment: Actually, your last line should be: totalCount = ResultProxy.fetchone()[0]